# SalvaPdfJsBundle: View PDFs in modal

Tags: php, symfony, pdf

I successfully integrated SalvaPdfJsBundle into my Symfony2 project:
https://github.com/nibsirahsieu/SalvaPdfJsBundle

However, the documentation is very poor, and I have not yet found a way to use it for displaying pdfs in my modal.

Currently, I preview my pdfs like this with an iframe:

**Results.html.twig**

```
<a href="#" data-url="files/my-file.pdf" class="show-modal">Preview PDF</a>

<div id="preview-modal">
        <div>
            <iframe src=""></iframe>
        </div>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $previewModal = $('#preview-modal');
        var previewModal = $previewModal.dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 1000,
            height: 'auto',
            modal: true,
            resizable: false
        });
        $('.show-modal').on('click', function () {
            var fileUrl = $(this).attr('data-url');
            $previewModal.find('iframe').attr('src', fileUrl);
            previewModal.dialog('open');
        });
    </script>
```

**What I want to achieve:**

- previewing the pdf inside the modal with SalvaPdfJS
- having a simple preview WITHOUT download option

Any ideas how to achieve this?